# Error al filtrar datos con sorter?

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy tratando de filtrar los datos con sorter, pero no resulta.

Las clases las tengo asi:

```
private DefaultTableModel modeloC;
private TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(modeloC);
```

Esta parte la pongo en el metodo constructor, para que se asigne cuando se inicia la vista:

```
    public frm_BuscarConcepto(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        modeloC = (DefaultTableModel) jt_Conceptos.getModel();
    }
```

De esta manera cargo los datos para que se muestren en la tabla:

```
private void cargarTabla()
{
    ArrayList<conceptosC_DAO> conceptos = concepto.getAssets();
    
    if(!conceptos.isEmpty())
    {
        for(conceptosC_DAO c : conceptos)
        {
            Object[] fila = {
                c.getCuenta(),
                c.getSubCuenta(),
                c.getDescripcion(),
                c.getDescripcion_Corta()
            };
            modeloC.addRow(fila);
        }
    }
}
```

Y el sorter lo aplico en el "KeyReleased" para que se pueda hacer el filtro cuando escribo algo en el JTextfield:

```
private void txt_BuscarKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + txt_Buscar.getText(), 2));
}
```

Queda señalar que de esta forma lo uso en otro JDialog y si me filtra los datos. Pero en los otros formularios que lo uso no me hace el filtro de los datos.

¿A que podrá deberse?

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude resolver de la siguiente manera.

En el método constructor agregue las siguientes líneas:

```
public frm_BuscarProveedoresAlmacen(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    initComponents();
    modeloProveedor = (DefaultTableModel) jt_Proveedores.getModel();
    jt_Proveedores.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(modeloProveedor);
    jt_Proveedores.setRowSorter(sorter);
}
```

Y con eso ya funciono bien.